# Need help coming up with an algorithm to generate a random boolean in Java depending on count and percentages

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I'm not sure if I even titled this post correctly. If I didn't, let me know and I'll edit the title.

What I am trying to do is simulate a "real-world" situation for charging batteries:

```
 1st charge == 100% chance of an error (a.k.a., boolean false)
 2nd charge == 90% chance of an error
 3rd charge == 80% chance of an error
 4th charge == 70% chance of an error
 5th charge == 60% chance of an error
 6th charge == 50% chance of an error
 7th charge == 40% chance of an error
 8th charge == 30% chance of an error
 9th charge == 20% chance of an error
10th charge == 10% chance of an error
```

So, what I need is an algorithm to generate a true or false depending on these percentages, but I have no idea how to do it. I know there is `Random` and `ThreadLocalRandom` but there is no way to input any bounds or values for `nextBoolean()`. I figured I could do something like this:

```
switch(charge){
    case 1:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(10,10) > 10) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 2:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(9,10) > 9) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 3:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(8,10) > 8) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 4:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(7,10) > 7) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 5:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(6,10) > 6) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 6:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(5,10) > 5) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 7:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(4,10) > 4) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 8:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(3,10) > 3) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 9:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(2,10) > 2) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
    case 10:
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(1,10) > 1) return ThreadLocalRandom.nextBoolean();
        break;
}
```

As you can see, I have no idea what I am doing, so I need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: no matter the case, the `return` is always the same so not usefull

Comment: the whole question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You're generating a random int and then immediately throwing it away and returning a completely separate random boolean!

Comment: You don’t need a ThreadLocalRandom. Just generate a random integer, define a cutoff value, and return true if the generated number is greater than cutoff.

Comment: `1st charge == 100% chance of an error` -- What is an "error" in the context of charging a battery, and why is the chance of error 100% (i.e. there's ALWAYS an error) the first time?

Comment: @JimGarrison It doesn't matter what the error is or why it happens, what matters is that I need help figuring this out with these parameters.

Comment: @Brian did you not see my answer ? :D it gives perfctly the % you ask for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.  Explanation and solution :**

What you need is :

- generate a random number (use `Random` class) between 0 and 10
- depending on the value of `charge`, find the range of acceptance for the random number :

  - *example :* if the charge is `4`, to get an error the random has to be is `[0;7]` (70% of the range) so `return random >=7;`

```
private static boolean isError(int charge) {
    int random = new Random().nextInt(10);
    switch (charge) {
        case 1:  return random >= 10;
        case 2:  return random >= 9;
        case 3:  return random >= 8;
        case 4:  return random >= 7;
        case 5:  return random >= 6;
        case 6:  return random >= 5;
        case 7:  return random >= 4;
        case 8:  return random >= 3;
        case 9:  return random >= 2;
        case 10: return random >= 1;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

---

**2. Shorter Solution**

This can be simplified in :

```
private static boolean isError(int charge) {
    return new Random().nextInt(10) >= (11 - charge);
}
```

---

**3. Tests & Demo** : [*Demo*](https://ideone.com/xDlJKH)

With this `main`, you can test the validity of the method, it tests `nbTest` times, each `charge`, and see how many times you got an error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##%");
    double nbError, nbTest = 100000;
    for (int charge = 1; charge < 11; charge++) {
        nbError = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nbTest; j++) {
            nbError += (isError(charge) ? 0 : 1);
        }
        System.out.println(charge + " -> " + df.format(nbError / nbTest));
    }
}


1 -> 100   %   ~100%
2 ->  90,06%   ~ 90%
3 ->  80,31%   ~ 80%
4 ->  69,97%   ~ 70%
5 ->  59,92%   ~ 60%
6 ->  49,9 %   ~ 50%
7 ->  39,9 %   ~ 40%
8 ->  30,08%   ~ 30%
9 ->  19,84%   ~ 20%
10 -> 10,18%   ~ 10%
```

Comment: The `Random` class is not really intended to be used like that, i.e. constructing a whole new `Random` object for every single random integer. It's meant to return an object that use then assign to a variable to use multiple times. Alternatively, you can use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` which returns a pre-initialized Random object.

Comment: @azro Looking back on this, wouldn't it be `case N: return random <= X`? If it were, say, `>= 10` then that would be greater than or equal to 100%, but if it were `<= 10` then it would be less than or equal to 100%, which is what I need ... correct?

Answer (score 1):

One simple mechanism would be to calculate a value between `0.0` and `1.0` dependent on the charge count and then just compare that with a random `double`.

```
public void test() {
    // Test each charge.
    for (int charge = 0; charge < 10; charge++) {
        // Using ints here so output is clearer - could just as easily use bool.
        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int test = 0; test <= 100; test++) {
            // Use 0 or 1 debending on random biased boolean.
            results.add(biasedBoolean(1.0 - ((float) charge / 10)) ? 0 : 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Charge " + (charge + 1) + " -> " + results);
    }
}

Random random = new Random();

private Boolean biasedBoolean(double bias) {
    return random.nextDouble() < bias;
}
```

You may need to tweak the maths to make sure you get the right statistics on your values but this certainly shows one technique.